# Routing Issues with Production Build of React Application

Tags: reactjs, deployment, routes, namecheap

So I'm trying to deploy my first React application live. It is my portfolio webiste. Anyways, everything is working fine except for my routes. Locally, Everything works fine. However, now that I've deployed the website my routes do not work. When you click on any of the links it says the url cannot be found on the server, and it throws a 404 error.

The application is hosted by namecheap, and they said they cannot see anything wrong from their end. I just have no idea what could be wrong then as it all works find locally.

My website can be found at andrewschubert.website and the github repo for this can be found at  https://github.com/theschubinator/my-portfolio If anyone has any ideas what I'm doing wrong I would greatly appreciate it!

By the way, it is a React Application. There is no database or API, just strictly front-end. The only links that are actually working are the ones that redirect you to an area outside of my application...like my blog on medium.

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you've been using `react-router` lib for your routing. It is based on `HTML5 history API`, which is not supported by every host out there. If you are talking about your portfolio website and it's not so much of and issue where do you deploy it, try out some different hosts (e.g. surge is great for deploying static sites: https://surge.sh/).

Answer (score 0):

React applications are single page. Routing in React means changing the components displayed when user requests a different url. You will need an api. 
On every client request you return the same "index.html" which will display only one component. By creating a controller in your server you can map "/contact" to "index.html#contact" and your hashrouter can return the ContactUs component.